# Forge - WebGL context lost when loading multiple models

Tags: autodesk-forge

Keep getting the error of WebGL context lost when multiple SVF1 files (about 10) are loaded. The error doesn't appear right away but after a few of the models are loaded.
How can I prevent this?

Comment: 10 files are a bit overloaded. May I know the file sizes and the error in the console, If any?